# Chat loading the same messages in all cells

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am developing an app that needs the chat functionality, presenting messages sent and received in an Table View. I am able to load the first message without any problem, but when a second message arrives, the first one is erased in the table and presents second message, but in two cells, the third messages in three cells and so on.

I am storing the messages in an `NSMutableArray`, and then I run that array:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];

NSLog(@"We are in cellForRowAtIndexPath de ChatViewController");
//UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
//if(!cell){
messarray=general.messarray;
for (int i=0;i<=messarray.count; i++)
{
    diccio=[messarray objectAtIndex:i];
    general.firstmess=[diccio objectForKey:@"msg"];
    general.firstfrom=[diccio objectForKey:@"sender"];

UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
//}
text=general.firstmess;
remite=general.firstfrom;
[[cell textLabel]setText:remite];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:text];

return cell;

}
}
```

Its like the `for` is not done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop assings the last message to the current cell
What you have to do is

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    General *general = [General sharedManager];

    NSLog(@"We are in cellForRowAtIndexPath de ChatViewController");
    messarray = general.messarray;

    //Get the element basing on the current row
    diccio=[messarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    general.firstmess=[diccio objectForKey:@"msg"];
    general.firstfrom=[diccio objectForKey:@"sender"];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    text = general.firstmess;
    remite = general.firstfrom;
    [[cell textLabel]setText:remite];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:text];

    return cell;
}
```

a suggestion is to implement `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` correctly

Comment: It worked perfectly, Omar. If you ever come to Spain i have a lot of whatever-you-drink waiting for you ;)

Comment: @Fustigador hehe you know, i may actually come :P, and consider accepting and/or upvoting :)